# IBM mq jms listener with batch

Tags: spring-boot, ibm-mq

I use spring boot application with jms listener.

I want to know , how to config IBM MQ JMSListener to consume batch messages instead single message. It is real?

Comment: Real?  What have you tried.   Why wouldn't you just consume multiple messages?  What exactly do you mean by "batch"?

Comment: I want to consume multiple messages , for example 50, and handle them all in one transaction, instead of consuming one message at time

Comment: You should use a transacted session then commit after 50.

Comment: could you give me some code exmple with ibm mq and  spring boot?